# Apache 403 code with python parsing

Tags: python, apache, https

I want to parse https site with python.

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/wap/auth/?serviceId=121&returnUrl=https://example.com'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,sr;q=0.2',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'example.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/47.0.2526.73 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)

print response.text
```

Answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /wap/auth/
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at example.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

But this link opens in browser normally with 200 http code without redirects. url and headers where copied from browser to python script. There is no redirects in python script. There is no proxies. Browser and python script are running on my computer(linux mint 17).

Why apache have banned my script and works fine with browser? is it possible to make this request from python script?

note: domain was changed to example.com

Comment: Have you tried looking at the headers chrome or firefox sends when it is opened using the developer panel ? Does the link work if you open a new incognito/in-private tab and open it ? Does it require you to login to the website ?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Headers in script where copied from chrome developer console. url was successfully tested in chrome, incognito chrome, firefox. it is not require to log in. cookies where deleted from browser. cookies is not sent according to chrome developer console.

Comment: Hm, is it possible for you to give the domain name ? I'm not sure what the problem could be. Wanted to test it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with openssl update. Server used tls 1.2 protocol. This type of protocol is available in browser, but unavailable in old script libraries. 
This commands are solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libevent-dev python-dev --upgrade
sudo pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1  --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not quite sure what the issue is with urllib ... I can suggest an alternative. Use `selenium`.

Selenium can load up a page like exactly how firefox sees it. It basically uses firefox's loader and loads the page including the JS and so on - making it much more easier for automation tasks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://login.tele2.ru/ssotele2/wap/auth/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
print driver.page_source
```

Comment: I know about selenium. It uses much more(about 100x) cpu in comparison with raw http requests. It also very unstable in production. Thank you for help!